# apache running locally(ubuntu) but not accessbile over the internet

Tags: apache

Computer A(Ubuntu machine) (10.192.13.161) with Apache is connected to internet.I want to access a web page from online (I placed login.php under /var/www/html folder) on (http://10.192.13.161/login.php) but can not connect. Firewall is disabled. any one has any idea why I am not able to access?

Comment: are you on the same network as that IP address and where are you trying to access it from?

Comment: not on the same network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if you mean you want to access it locally or actually online. To check if your local webserver is running you can try going to `localhost` in your browser. If that works and it points to the `/var/www/html` folder then you can try `localhost/login.php`, but of course this requires that you have php set up.

`10.192.13.161` is your local network address. Files on your local computer are not viewable online (which is a good thing since it would make it a lot less safe). If you want to use this login.php file online you'll need to get it hosted it on a server.

Comment: I want to access the page online. I was able to access pages through online few years back. Not sure, why it is not happening now. ? any idea?

Comment: @sravanmummadi that's because you have to use your WAN/public ip address [shown here](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=whats%20my%20ip) not your local. but you have to do some work like port forwarding with your router and stuff.

Answer (score 0):

What does

```
    netstat -nlp
```

give you? Is there an apache listening on Port 80?

What is in your apache (vhost-) config? (F.e. : /etc/apach2/conf.d/000-default.conf)

Comment: It may not matter at all if he's trying to **actually** access this link over the internet. That is a private IP address and only routes on a LAN and is not available from outside that network.

Comment: So how are you connected to the internet? Is there a router in your network with a firewall?
If you want to access a machine in your private network, you need to implement a path to it. 
You need a port forwarding from your accesspoint / Router to your local machine.

Comment: And you need at least your public IP (https://www.whatismyip.com/). 
The public IP is pointing to your accesspoint/router. There the port 80 have to be forwarded to your local machine 10.192.13.161 (also port 80).

Afterwards you should be able to call:
http://YOURPUBLICIP/login.php

For more support we need to know more about your local infrastructure (Routername / Model ....)